# Logging data passed to the queue is not working as expected

Tags: logging, laravel, laravel-4, queue

I am trying to work with laravel 4.1 queues. I have the code below

```
Queue::push('TopicQueue', array('string' => 'Hello World'));
```

and the TopicQueue is as follows

```
class TopicQueue {

    public function fire($job, $data){
         Log::info('This is from the worker thread . The data array is = '.var_export($data));

        $job->delete();

    }

}
```

In the log I am getting this

> [2014-05-14 03:19:02] production.INFO: This is from the worker thread . The data array is =  [] []

My question is "How do I pass data , to the TopicQueue  fire method ? If I am doing something wrong, can somebody please point it out for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

```
Log::info('This is from the worker thread . The data array is = '.var_export($data));
```

to

```
Log::info('This is from the worker thread . The data array is = '.var_export($data, true));
```

Comment: works .. thanks .. unfortunately I cannot accept right now.. I am being asked to wait for 9 minutes. thanks once again!